# How to extract data from the html contents of a webpage using an Android application?

Tags: html, android-wifi

For simplicity lets say I have a single webpage with 10 lines of html code. I have a single h3 header tag like e.g.

#### Mydata: 12345

The numeric data changes on the server side. I need to constantly monitor this number in the Android application over a WiFi network while not causing any performance lags on the UI. Currently I can load the webpage  inside a WebView component in Android and see the data refresh every 10 secs.

What  is the simplest solution to access the numeric data within the java code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was the simplest approach but i have sub-classed AsyncTask and used HttpURLConnection to access the html code in the webpage.